# ERD without relationships

Tags: database, sql-server-data-tools, erd

I haven't touched database since graduated from school, so please forgive me if my question is too entry level.

As i remember how to draw ERD with UML, recently, my boss asked me to create a database for inventory system with frontend. I googled some similar systems and found that in backend their databases don't have any relationships between tables ( i did DB reversed UML ).

So I thought about it, it seems application works fine even without relationships ( no foreign keys ), so what's the point we have reasons we still need relationship between tables?

Comment: The foreign keys will enforce referential integrity between the tables. Also generally means an index is created, though you can do that through other means if you wish. But point 1 is the key.

Comment: I had exactly the same experience about 8 years ago. This is very common in the data warehousing world. good question.

Comment: @Z4-tier this is done in data warehouses because querying for certain KPI's might be speed up by introducing redundancy. As the data in the warehouse often comes from a relational system (it is sort of a copy) the risk of inconstancy is pretty low.

Comment: @RuudHermans Very true, but also keep in mind there are 2 kinds of denormalization: the good kind, and the bad kind. The good kind is created intentionally and with a specific goal (usually performance).  The bad kind is unintended and can happen when the same data is landed from 2 separate upstream systems. If that duplicated data is never reconciled or otherwise dealt with, it's a problem. It's even worse when that duplicate data is not consistent (like finance data taken from a system used for managerial planning, versus accounting data from the system used to prepare SEC filings).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the areas where there is often a noticeable disparity between the theory that is taught in CS courses and the reality of what happens in practice.

Often what you'll run into is a mash-up between the two: an ERD model that shows all the proper relationships and keys, and the "reality" of what actually gets implemented in the database.

The implementation side is probably the part that catches people by surprise, as you have seen: no relationships defined, and foreign keys are simply implied by the matching column names across different tables. This is a tradeoff.

One one hand, managing foreign keys in a database has overhead. Every time a row is added or modified, the database will need to examine those foreign keys and make sure that the change will preserve the relational integrity. After all, that's what you are asking for when you define those relationships, right? And in an ideal world where that overhead is negligible, this is probably a good thing, because as DBA's we like it when our physical implementation matches the idealized model we spent all that time creating. We sleep better knowing that every entry in the `customer` table references a valid location in the `company_location` table.

On the other hand, there is reality. That overhead is not something we can easily ignore. Not when that nightly batch load is 4 hours late, and some marketing manager is asking you every 10 minutes for an estimate on when his data will be available. So we cut some corners and make some compromises. And hey, we're pretty good programmers, right? Certainly we can code the application in a way that will always maintain the referential integrity of the database without having to spend all that extra time to deal with foreign keys in the database....well, maybe.... the truth is that it is **really** hard to be sure that RI will always be preserved by an application that is already implementing some potentially complex business logic.

There are, of course, many other reasons for using explicit RI, and plenty of good reasons for ignoring it in the physical implementation. You are right, at the end of the day applications often do work OK without relationships being defined. And at the end of the day, I will probably get home safe even if I don't put on my seatbelt for the drive. But having the relationships implemented in the database is a pretty solid insurance policy when it comes to guaranteeing the integrity our a data. Analysts that use that database to generate business insights like consistent data. And transactional applications might depend on the assumption that the data is relationally consistent.

Î guess my point is that there is no "always right" answer here, and it really is a case-by-base thing. I would just suggest to start from the assumption that you'll physically implement the model, complete with RI, as faithfully as possible. Then, if you find hot spots, carefully and conservatively relax those constraints as needed.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation,  I tried with some dummy data (about 50k entries in one table, in production, there are more entries), by selecting all entries to display on frontend, it took a little time to get result, if it had some FK referring to other tables, that could be much slower, however, i expect frontend retrieve datagrid in a timely fashion, i guess the RI job should be done rely on application side in this case ?

Comment: @ikel Implementing foreign keys should have no negative impact on the performance of a SELECT, since FK's do not impose any requirements on _read_ operations. Foreign keys **can** add overhead to _create_, _update_, and _delete_ operations, depending on the relationship between the tables and the type of FK that is used. If you have a SELECT query with bad performance, you might be able to improve it by adding appropriate indexes to the underlying table(s), running `collect statistics`, or a number of other techniques (but removing RI will not help).

Answer (score 1):

Foreign key's take care of referential integrity.

To explain this a bit more: By adding a foreign key you are saying "what is in this column must be in the column I am pointing to as well". This makes sure your naming stay's consistent.

If you did not do this mistakes could be introduced when adding redundant information. Like calling "James", "Jamed" by mistake.